# how to take the value from the array if the value is separated by the semicolon

Tags: php

i have an array which have two values which are separated by the semicolon out of that i only want the the value which is after the semicolon.

```
Array ( [0] => animals;1 [1] => animals;2 [2] => animals;3 [3] => birds;1 [4] => birds;2 )
```

i am getting  the output

```
Array ( [animals] => 1 ) 
Array ( [animals] => 2 ) 
Array ( [animals] => 3 ) 
Array ( [animals] => 3 [birds] => 1 ) 
Array ( [animals] => 3 [birds] => 2 )
```

i want the output

```
Array ( [animals] => 1 ) 
Array ( [animals] => 2 ) 
Array ( [animals] => 3 ) 
Array ( [birds] => 1 ) 
Array ( [birds] => 2 )
```

i have tried

```
 $filter_param = array();

                    foreach ($animals as $options)
                    {
                        $exp_data = explode(";",$options);
                        //echo "<br>";
                        //print_r($exp_data);
                        $filter_string = '';
                        foreach ($exp_data as $dta)
                        {
                            $filter_string .= $dta[].',';
                        }

                        $filter_string = $exp_data[1];

                        $filter_string = rtrim($filter_string,",");

                        $filter_param[$exp_data[0]] = $filter_string;


                        echo "<br>";
                        print_r($filter_param);
                    }
```

Comment: try this much only:- `$filter_param = array();

foreach ($animals as $options)
{
    $exp_data = explode(";",$options);
    $filter_param[$exp_data[0]] = $exp_data[1];
}echo "<pre/>";print_r( $filter_param);`

Comment: check here:- https://eval.in/665930

Comment: Its wrong I have same code pasted on answer but User need it like this : Array ( [animals] => 1 ) Array ( [animals] => 2 ) Array ( [animals] => 3 ) Array ( [birds] => 1 ) Array ( [birds] => 2 ).  so I have corrected my code. @Anant

Comment: @RuchishParikh  you add another `foreach` only for printing? So what's the big deal there

Comment: yeah, but user want same output so i have printed same as they needed. @Anant

Comment: @RuchishParikh   lol. you need to tell to OP only , BTW good to add in code. Don't worry

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = Array ( 0 => "animals;1", 1 => "animals;2", 2 => "animals;3", 3 => "birds;1", 4 => "birds;2" );

foreach($arr as $key=>$row)
{
    $tmparr = explode(";", $row);
    $newArr[][$tmparr[0]] = $tmparr[1];
}

foreach($newArr as $new)
{
    print_r($new);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [animals] => 1 )
Array ( [animals] => 2 )
Array ( [animals] => 3 )
Array ( [birds] => 1 )
Array ( [birds] => 2 )
```

**Demo:  [Click Here](https://eval.in/665925)**

Comment: i want it like this

Comment: Array ( [animals] => 1 ) 
Array ( [animals] => 2 ) 
Array ( [animals] => 3 ) 
Array ( [birds] => 1 ) 
Array ( [birds] => 2 )

Comment: while i am getting like this

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [animals] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [animals] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [animals] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [birds] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [birds] => 2 ) )

Comment: Hope you will now get your answer from this updated code. Please give your feedback with accept the answer and positive response. :) @Ninad